# How to setContent in wysiwyg editor using JQuery in magento2?

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

I have one WYSIWYG editor in admin custom form which was created using the UI component.

I want to set content using JQuery in magento2

Can anyone help me?

```
    define([
        'underscore',
        'uiRegistry',
        'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
        'mage/url',
        'wysiwygAdapter'
    ], function (_, uiRegistry, select, url,tinyMCE) {
        'use strict';
        return select.extend({

            initialize: function (){
                var obj = this;
                var type= this._super().initialValue;
                this.makevisilibily(type);

                var defaultTemplate=uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_template');

                defaultTemplate.on('update',function(){
                   obj.displayTemplateImage(defaultTemplate.value());
                })

                jQuery('body').on('click',"#banner_load_template_btn",function(){
                    var toggleMCEEditor = jQuery('#togglebanner_form_content');
                    var defaultTemplate=uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_template');
                    var templateContent=obj.displayTemplateContent(defaultTemplate.value());

                       toggleMCEEditor.trigger('click');

                      tinyMCE.get('textarea#banner_form_content').setContent(templateContent);
                })
                return this;

            },

            /**
             * On value change handler.
             *
             * @param {String} value
             */
            onUpdate: function (value) {
                this.makevisilibily(value);
                var defaultTemplate=uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_template');

                  this.displayTemplateImage(defaultTemplate.value());
                return this._super();
            },

            makevisilibily: function (value) {

                var field1 = uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_template');
                var field2 = uiRegistry.get('banner_form.areas.general.general.default_image');
                var field3 = jQuery('body').find('.bannerwysiwygClass');
                var field4 = jQuery('body').find(".bannerimageClass");

                if (value == 1) {
                    field1.visible(true);
                    field2.visible(true);
                    field3.show();
                    field4.hide();
                } else {
                    field1.visible(false);
                    field2.visible(false);
                    field3.hide();
                    field4.show();
                }

                return this._super();
            },
              displayTemplateImage: function (defaultTemplate) { 
                var data = this.getContentAndImage(defaultTemplate);
                jQuery("#mp-demo-image").attr("src",data['imgSrc']);

                },

                displayTemplateContent: function (defaultTemplate) { 
                var data = this.getContentAndImage(defaultTemplate);
                return data['templateContent'];

                },


                getContentAndImage:function (defaultTemplate) {
                    var imgSrc="";
                    var templateContent="";
                    var data =[];
                    if(defaultTemplate=="demo1.png")
                    {
                        imgSrc=window.defaultTemplate1;
                        templateContent=window.defaultContent1;
                    }
                    else if(defaultTemplate=="demo2.png")
                    {
                      imgSrc=window.defaultTemplate2;
                      templateContent=window.defaultContent2;
                    }
                    else if(defaultTemplate=="demo3.png")
                    {
                      imgSrc=window.defaultTemplate3;
                      templateContent=window.defaultContent3;
                    }
                    else if(defaultTemplate=="demo4.jpg")
                    {
                      imgSrc=window.defaultTemplate4;
                      templateContent=window.defaultContent4;
                    }
                    else if(defaultTemplate=="demo5.jpg")
                    {
                      imgSrc=window.defaultTemplate5;
                      templateContent=window.defaultContent5;
                    }
                    data['imgSrc'] = imgSrc;
                    data['templateContent'] = templateContent;
                    return data;
                }
            });
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try below code

```
tinyMCE.get('your_textarea_id').setContent("test");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! working fine

Comment: How i can do this if Data is in html and Multiline?

Comment: not workikng for me error "Cannot read property 'setContent' of null"